# Python: no if in second loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, while-loop, iteration

Im not sure if Im nuts or something, but look at this code:

```
a=1
while a<=2.2:
    if a==1.4:
        print "OK"
    a=a+0.4
```

output: "OK"

changed condition to 1.8:

```
a=1
while a<=2.2:
    if a==1.8:
        print "OK"
    a=a+0.4
```

output: nothing!?

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: I'm not sure, but my first guess is that you are having a problem with the precision of floating point numbers.  Try the same with integers.

Comment: Just try `1.4 + 0.4` and see what you get.

Comment: use an epsilon,  `if abs(1.8 - a) <= epsilon` where epsilon is 0.00001

Answer (score 1):

Testing random floats for equality is usually a bad idea.  It's probably something like 1.799999999.

Check out [this link](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the round function

```
In [19]: round(6.79999999,1)
Out[19]: 6.8
```